# how can I set up this equation for constrained maximization?

Tags: r

[image]

How i can write this equation inside R as a function?
subject to: 20* x[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/duMzw.png) + 170*x[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hATt6.png) = 20000
[image]

```
#ATTEMPT
library(Rsolnp)
fn <- function(h, s){
  z=200 * x[1]^(2/3) * x[2]^(1/3)
  return(-z)}
# constraint z1: 20*x+170*y=20000
eqn <- function(x) { 
  z1=20*x[1] + 170*x[2]
  return(c(z1))
}
constraints = c(20000)

x0 <- c(1, 1) # setup init values
sol1 <- solnp(x0, fun = fn, eqfun = eqn, eqB = constraints)
sol1$pars
```

Comment: `R <- function(h, s)200 * h^(2/3) * s^(1/3)`

Comment: Do you want to write this function for display or to actually run it?

Comment: @Onyambu, please post as an answer

Comment: i want to write this function to maximize with Rsolnp, subject to:  20*x[1] + 170*x[2] = 20000

Comment: it would be better to write your question as "how can I set up this equation for constrained maximization?" As you can see from @Onyambu's answer (which is a perfectly good response to your initial question), your first version was too vague

Comment: I thought that only the equation is wrong, the constraint is right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In R, we would use the keyword `function`, and we would pass the necessary parameters:

for example in this case.

```
R <- function(h, s)200 * h^(2/3) * s^(1/3)
```

We now have a function called R, that takes in arguments h and s and gives us an output.

For example, we could do:

```
 R(27, 8)
```

Comment: i only change (h, s) to (x) and x[1] and x[2] inside the function